# Hasura: Subscriptions - no subprotocols supported

Tags: python, websocket, graphql, hasura

```
subscription = Template('''
    subscription {
        users {
            id
            name
        }
    }
''')

async def user_listener():

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'x-hasura-access-key': 'mysecretkey'}

    uri = "ws://localhost:8080/v1alpha1/graphql"
    async with websockets.connect(uri, extra_headers=headers) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(subscription.render())
        while True:
            greeting = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"< {greeting}")


def main():
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(user_listener())
```

I am using python [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) to implement a simple listener using Hasura graphql subscription. However I hit the following exception when I run the above program. (Note I am trying out hasura on my laptop using docker-compose)

```
  File "listener.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "listener.py", line 35, in main
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(infradb_listener())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "listener.py", line 27, in infradb_listener
    async with websockets.connect(uri, extra_headers=headers) as websocket:
  File "/Users/vpatil3/projects/hasura-ws-example/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 517, in __aenter__
    return await self
  File "/Users/vpatil3/projects/hasura-ws-example/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 547, in __await_impl__
    extra_headers=protocol.extra_headers,
  File "/Users/vpatil3/projects/hasura-ws-example/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 305, in handshake
    response_headers, available_subprotocols
  File "/Users/vpatil3/projects/hasura-ws-example/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/client.py", line 207, in process_subprotocol
    raise InvalidHandshake("no subprotocols supported")
websockets.exceptions.InvalidHandshake: no subprotocols supported
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue got fixed by adding **subproctocols** to the websocket connect API as follows

```
 async with websockets.connect(uri, subprotocols='graphql-ws', extra_headers=headers) as websocket:
```

Comment: thanks for that tip with subprotocols. Can I ask you how you are formatting your subscription on python side? I see you have some Template() and render() methods in your code. When I test on my box with my subscription as pure string its failing with the message: "{"type":"connection_error","payload":"parsing ClientMessage failed: Error in $: Failed reading: not a valid json value at 'subscriptionMySubscription{'"}" but I am not sure how to change that subscription grahpql syntax to be recognized as valid json.

Comment: Why are you using Template? Where is it coming from?